# What are the security risks associated with hosting Laravel website on a shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, security, shared-hosting

I many articles where writers show how to deploy a Laravel app/website on shared hosting they [discourage doing that.](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6) In some other [quora questions](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-downsides-of-hosting-a-Laravel-app-on-shared-hosting) where the answers state that it is possible but has some security risks. So what security risks does this practice implies.

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer depends on the type of project and-or customer (agency vs interprise).

If you are working for a smaller project and there is no on-going development (extra possible invoicing) to it I will recommend using a shared hosting.

But if your budget is pretty high and that application needs to grow, handles sensitive user data, automated deployments, unit testing together with Docker and Vagrant for local development. I would recommend using **AWS** or **digital ocean**.

The biggest problem using AWS is that it pushes the responsibility to you in keeping the operating system and PHP-version up-to-date.

With interprise customers, I would recommend using services like:

- Use a security scan (https://detectify.com/)
- Use a Firewall (https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/)

Basically it all depends on the type of customer you are dealing with.

But for a really small / tiny projects, just use a shared hosting and basically never forget to use CSRF, ReCaptcha, throttling requests, ... Be smart about it.